# How can I return a joined table as an enumerable on an anonymous return type in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'd like to return an object with the following signature

```
class AnonClass{
    string Name {get;}
    IEnumerable<Group> Groups {get;}
}
```

I have tried the following query, but g only returns a single entity, not all the joined entities

```
var q = from t in dc.Themes
join g in dc.Groups on t.K equals g.ThemeK 
select new {t.Name, Groups = g};
return q.ToArray();
```

but this returns

```
class AnonClass{
   string Name {get;}
   Group Groups{get;}
}
```

What is the correct linq query to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want "join into" instead of just "join":

```
var q = from t in dc.Themes
        join g in dc.Groups on t.K equals g.ThemeK into groups
        select new { t.Name, Groups=groups };
```

(That's completely untested, however - worth a try, but please verify carefully!)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Foreign Key set up correctly, then it should be:

```
var q = from t in dc.Themes
select new {t.Name, Groups = t.Groups};
```

Comment: I had something like this earlier, but the Groups property gets lazy loaded, resulting in loads of sql calls when I try to enumerate it.